# 'npm audit' fix or 'npm audit'

Tags: angular, npm-audit

I get this when I try installing @angular/cdk: run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit`.
Is this version conflicts that occur when I install? I'm assuming that conflicts that occur in package.json causes this.

Can some one tell why this occurs and what is this?

Comment: It means that some of the dependencies in your project have vulnerabilities. As it says, you can run `npm audit`; this will show a list of all such dependencies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How npm audit works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55569305/how-npm-audit-works)

Comment: What causes these vulnerabilities? Is that version issues alone or anything else?